# zoomScale, contentOffset and Retina

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I have [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026650/scrollview-contentoffset-zoomscale) [into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604276/change-zoomscale-and-contentoffset-of-uiscrollview-in-uiapplicationstatebackgrou) [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301744/unwanted-scrolling-when-animating-zoomscale-in-uiscrollview) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051361/how-much-contentoffset-changes-in-uiscrollview-for-zooming) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160206/uiscrollview-and-zoomscale) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854547/updating-zoomscale-of-uiscrollview) but none of them seem to address the issue I'm facing.

The short of it is that my scroll/zooming code works as I expect it to on *pre retina* devices, but on 4, 4S & 5 with iOS 5.x & 6.x my code works for any value of the zoom below 1.0 I tested it with, but breaks when zoomScale is precisely 1.0 or above.

At that point the whole view is shifted towards the top/left

This code:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews] ;

    ::NSLog(@"x:%.02f contentOffset (%0.2f:%0.2f)"
    ,   self.zoomScale
    ,   self.contentOffset.x
    ,   self.contentOffset.y) ;
}
```

produces this on retina: (**jerky transition** for zoomScale from less than 1.0 to greater than 1.0)

```
x:0.96 contentOffset (1334.37:622.55)
x:0.98 contentOffset (1371.34:639.45)
x:1.00 contentOffset (226.45:202.26) 
x:1.02 contentOffset (227.59:204.19) 
x:1.03 contentOffset (228.71:206.10)
```

produces this on NON retina: (**smooth transition** for zoomScale from less than 1.0 to greater than 1.0)

```
x:0.95 contentOffset (2211.01:2247.41) 
x:0.97 contentOffset (2257.25:2295.54) 
x:0.99 contentOffset (2303.52:2343.69) 
x:1.03 contentOffset (2403.40:2447.63) 
x:1.05 contentOffset (2457.57:2504.00)
```

Anyone?

**EDIT** Logging the scrolled/zoomed view transform produces consistent (and still wrong!) results:

Non Retina

```
scale:0.98 contentOffset(29.11:40.02) transform: [0.978491, 0, 0, 0.978491, 0, 0]
scale:0.99 contentOffset(31.79:43.71) transform: [0.992378, 0, 0, 0.992378, 0, 0]
scale:1.01 contentOffset(35.71:49.11) transform: [1.01268, 0, 0, 1.01268, 0, 0]
scale:1.03 contentOffset(38.40:52.79) transform: [1.02656, 0, 0, 1.02656, 0, 0]
scale:1.04 contentOffset(41.09:56.49) transform: [1.04048, 0, 0, 1.04048, 0, 0]
```

Retina

```
scale:0.98 contentOffset(1377.56:1511.69) transform: [0.984364, 0, 0, 0.984364, 0, 0]
scale:0.99 contentOffset(1392.50:1528.51) transform: [0.993929, 0, 0, 0.993929, 0, 0]
scale:1.02 contentOffset(227.42:300.11) transform: [1.01742, 0, 0, 1.01742, 0, 0]
scale:1.03 contentOffset(228.26:301.48) transform: [1.02922, 0, 0, 1.02922, 0, 0]
scale:1.03 contentOffset(228.48:301.84) transform: [1.03236, 0, 0, 1.03236, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

When I replaced in the initialization

```
 self.scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize) {CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX} ;
```

with

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize) {1e9, 1e9} ;
```

Then the zoomScale and contentOffset become consistant across retina and non retina device.

My guess is that when Apple introduced the retina devices, they also (inadvertently?) *reduced the span of the floating point coordinate space* from

**[CGFLOAT_MIN, CGFLOAT_MAX]**

to

**[undefined, CGFLOAT_MAX/retina-device-scale]**

...